# How to get HttpResponse size

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, httpresponse

I'm looking for a way to get the number of bytes sent up to a certain point in an ASP.NET 2.0 response so that I can write this number into the response. Something like:

Page.aspx:

```
<script runat="server">
    private string GetResponseSize()
    {
        int nCurrentResponseSize = ...; // what goes here?
        return ( nCurrentResponseSize.ToString() );
    }
</script>
<html>
  <head runat="server"><title>test</title></head>
  <body>
    <div>Size 1: <%= GetResponseSize() %></div>
    <br />
    <div>Size 2: <%= GetResponseSize() %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `HttpResponse.OutputStream.Length` is not supported ([NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.80%29) doesn't support it).

I could implement an [`HtmlTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter%28v=vs.80%29) to override the page's default one and count bytes but something inside ASP.NET should already have the count and I'm trying to see if it's possible to get it.

What I'd like to avoid is solutions that involve getting all the data and then parsing it to a certain point to find the size up to that point. So far most of my searches only turned up these kind of solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dotPeek I found that HttpResponse has an internal GetBufferedLength method that is used to calculate the size of a control for tracing:

```
int bufferedLength1 = httpContext.Response.GetBufferedLength();
this.RenderControlInternal(writer, adapter);
int bufferedLength2 = httpContext.Response.GetBufferedLength();
```

It's not ideal, but you could call this method via reflection.

Comment: Thank you for the response - unfortunately, I also need to do this fast, so reflection is not really an option. I'll check it out anyway to see if I learn something from it - I wonder if it keeps the character count or the byte count.

Comment: 1) Might I ask why do you need this?

Comment: 2)Reflection is certainly slow purely in the context of access, but in the full context of a data driven website that is accessing files or even a database, we're probably talking a very small fraction of the total page processing time.

Comment: I need this because I'm working on a tool that sits in the HTTP pipeline and inspects/modifies traffic. It needs to be as fast as possible to only introduce a minimal performance drop.

Comment: Interesting.  Based on that description, maybe consider a HttpFilter instead?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx  Although, your UI component in your original question throws me off then.  Were you just using this for debugging purposes?

Comment: An HttpFilter may be the only choice, yes. I started looking into that a few days ago and the only real option that seems available is to hook into the response stream and then count bytes as they're written into the output. There are other issues with this - a buffered response doesn't seem to write into the output stream until the response is ready. Chunk encoded responses do pass through the filter in my tests.

The purpose of this is to embed usage data into the response as it goes out so that other components may parse it later on.

Comment: It's somewhat unsettling that .NET has no way to get this information in a simple way. I'm still testing this solution but if it works out, I'll accept your answer, since you're the only one who suggested it.