# how to capture response size (content-length) in global.asax?

Tags: c#, logging, httpresponse, global-asax

I'm trying to capture the http response content-length or the response size in global.asax using the following codes.

Option 1

```
var buffer = new MemoryStream();
this.LogInfoForOperations(String.Format("Response Size: {0}", buffer.Length));
```

Option 2

```
HttpApplication myHttpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
this.LogInfoForOperations(String.Format("Response Size: {0}", myHttpApplication.Context.Response.OutputStream.Length));
```

Error / Output:

```
[Error] An unhandled exception has been caught by Global.asax Application_Error handler...The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at AppName.Web.MvcApplication.Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)


[Information] Response Size: System.Web.HttpResponse
```

For some reason, those 2 codes that I came up with does not throw the size of the response. Can you please help me figure out what the equivalent value of request.totalbytes when getting the response size? I can get the request size using `Request.TotalBytes` but not the http response.

***UPDATE 31052017

I got a working code now however I always get 9 response size and it does not look accurate. Is there any suggestions you can give me to improve my code below? I need this to determine which transaction is consuming a lot of request and response aside from the time i get from new relic.

```
int responseLength = HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType.Length;
this.LogInfoForOperations(String.Format("Response Size: {0}", responseLength));
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.AddCustomParameter("responseSize", responseLength);
```

Comment: Is your code called as part of [HttpApplication.EndRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest.aspx)? You need to wait for the response to be fully formed before you can determine its size.

Comment: yes, i put the code in Application_EndRequest. i tried using different httpresponse properties but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: This question sounds the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625005/how-to-get-httpresponse-size

Comment: yup i also look at that one but it didn't work. :(

Comment: You need to provide some more details about exactly what "didn't work", what are the results when you try different things?

Comment: thanks, ive just edited my posting. sorry about that, im fairly new to posting messages in stackoverflow.

i get an undhandled exception as outlined above.

Comment: Are you using break points? Looks like accessing the response is timing out. What are you trying to achieve by getting the size, there may be a better alternative. It's not clear if what you want is even possible; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385689/get-response-output-size

Comment: no, i have a working code now but i have a feeling that it is not that accurate. see my updated msg above

Comment: You are only getting the length of the [Response.ContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx) for the response which if it's `text/HTML` is 9 characters.

Comment: what's the best way i can capture the entire response size?

Comment: @newbie where you able to solve this problem? Please share ?